# Python using requests to perform a GET to receive a application/json object

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to get a json object returned from my api. Using python's request framework to GET a json object from the api. Content type returns application/json when run so the content is json.

```
url = 'theUrl'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.headers['content-type'])
data = json.load(response)
```

The script when ran returns:

raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded.

There's also another issue when carrying out the request the api throws an error. The api's error log produces an error of

message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor:MessageBodyWriter not found for media type={text/html}

I've tried various different approaches to this but can't seem to receive the json object. Anyone encounter similar issues?

Comment: Do you mean to have `data = json.loads(response.json)`?

Answer (score 0):

The last two lines make no sense. You call `response.json()` and then ignore the return value, and then try to call `json.loads()` on the response itself, rather than the actual response content.

Instead of those two lines, just do `data = response.json()` which already returns the deserialized data.

Comment: Sorry the first call was a typo when I was writing the question. I added 

   data = json.loads(response.json)

Getting a new error but its more helpful. Pretty new to this. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

The return value from requests.get is not a string but an object. The response body is in .text property, thus:

```
data = json.loads(response.text)
```

And you are done

Comment: Receiving this error from the api now : 

MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml,

You guys have helped alot though believe I can figure rest myself thanks for your input and cheers @Daniel Roseman